# editing yml file using command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml

I would want to edit my yml file from the command line. Its on a ubuntu server.

```
version: "2"
services:
  samson:
    image: zendesk/samson:latest # replace with `build: .` to use Dockerfile (--build to rebuild it)
    ports:
      - "3000:9080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "sqlite3:///app/db/development.sqlite3"
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 1
```

I would like to add an environment variable in the environment section. I would like to do this from the command line. I have tried sed and echo. It does get added but without the correct indentation and yml format is very syntax sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be using [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```
cat mytemplate.yml | yq -Y '.services.samson.environment += {"newKey":"newVal"}'
```

Comment: Its asking me to write it in this format
`yq write [yaml_file] [path_expression] [value] [flags] `
I used this command
`yq w docker-compose.yml "services.samson[0].environment[0].value" "val"`
It throws this error:
```Error: Error reading document at index 0, yaml: line 12: could not find expected ':': yaml: line 12: could not find expected ':'
Usage:
  yq write [yaml_file] [path_expression] [value] [flags]```

Comment: .@sagar the command I gave you is correct.

Comment: I tried it Im getting this error
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'Y' in -Y

Answer (score 0):

Have you used 'yq' instead of 'sed' since it understands yaml format whereas sed treats them as strings so it would give incorrect indentation.

Comment: Yes I tried using this command: cat mytemplate.yml | yq -Y '.services.samson.environment += {"newKey":"newVal"}'
But I  keep getting this error 
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'Y' in -Y